# A result of Schützenberger on commutators and powers in free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

It is an old result of Schützenberger that in a free group, a basic commutator cannot be a proper power. A look at the original reference

M.-P. Schützenberger, *Sur l'équation $a^{2+n} = b^{2+m}c^{2+p}$ dans un groupe libre*, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 248 (1959), 2435–2436 (French).

quickly reveals that a lot of details are missing and some claims appear to be wrong.

> **Question:** Let $F$ be a free group and $a,b,c \in F$ with $c \neq 1$ and $n \geq 2$. Why is $[a,b] \neq c^n$?

In particular, it would be nice to have a somewhat geometric proof of this apparently fundamental fact. There is an algebraic proof in

G. Baumslag, *Some aspects of groups with unique roots*, Acta Math 104(3) (1960), 217–303.

as Lemma 36.4 but it is relies on various technical computations and is hard to grasp.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The case $n=2$ (originally due to Lyndon) admits a very nice geometric argument: one notes that elements $a,b,c$ with $[a,b]=c^2$ lead to a map from the surface $\Sigma_{-1}$ of Euler characteristic -1 to a graph.  Pulling back midpoints of edges, one obtains essential, two-sided, simple closed curves on $\Sigma_{-1}$.  Pinching these, Euler characteristic shows that one of the resulting components must be a projective plane, and the result follows.

For $n> 2$, [Duncan--Howie](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02571522) proved the stronger theorem that, for any non-trivial element $c$ of $F_2$, the stable commutator length of $c$ is at least $1/2$.  (In fact, by passing to covers, one can also deduce the $n=2$ case from the Duncan--Howie theorem.)  When you decode it, their proof is quite geometric, relying on defining a sort of combinatorial vector field on surfaces.

[Louder and I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2540) gave a sort of generalization of Duncan--Howie's proof in our work on one-relator groups. Again, the idea is to count Euler characteristic using some sort of geometric data (we call it a *stacking*).    We don't spell it out explicitly, but you can use our ideas to give a geometric proof of the Duncan--Howie theorem, and in particular of the result that you want.

Comment: How does the result for $n>2$ follow from the Duncan-Howie theorem? the latter a priori says nothing for fixed $n$, at least in the way you state it (which is something asymptotic on $c^n$ for $n\to\infty$)?

Comment: @Yves, ${scl}(w)$ is the *infimum* of the commutator lengths of $w^n$ over $n$.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought of it as a limit and not an infimum, so now I see why $n=2$ is special.

Comment: Actually, I do not understand all this about $n=2$. Duncan and Howie do not use the term **scl** at all. Their Theorem 5.1 implies, in particular, that, *a non-identity product of $k$ commutators in a free group cannot be an $n$th power for $n\geqslant2k$.* What is special for $n=2$?

Comment: @AntonKlyachko, you’re quite right: the Duncan—Howie theorem also handles the $n=2$ case. I confused myself by rephrasing the result in terms of scl, and then using the “wrong” definition of scl, namely as the stablised commutator length.  (Since this was four years ago, I don’t remember why I wanted to do it this way!) If you use the correct definition of scl, namely as the stabilised Euler characteristic, then indeed there’s nothing special about the $n=2$ case.  Thanks for pointing this out. Perhaps I’ll rewrite the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 11):

> (a) On the free 2-step nilpotent group $L$ on $(u,v)$, the commutator $z=[u,v]$ is not a proper power.

Indeed, since $L/[L,L]$ is torsion-free, any root of $z$ should lie in $[L,L]$ and the latter is readily seen to be the cyclic group generated by $z$. (Remark: $L$ is isomorphic to the integral 3-dimensional Heisenberg group.)$\qquad\Box$

I'll use three other very classical facts, without proof: the hardest (b) has both geometric and combinatorial proofs (the simplest using that $\pi_1$ of graphs are free), while (c),(d) are elementary exercises ((c) follows from Malcev's more general results but is very easy by hand here).

> (b) Subgroups of free groups are free.
>
> (c) $L$ is Hopfian (all its surjective group endomorphisms are automorphisms).
>
> (d) If $N$ is a nilpotent group and $M$ a subgroup generating $N$ modulo $[N,N]$ (that is, $M[N,N]=N$), then $M=N$.

This allows to prove the result.

> In a free group $F$, if $a,b,c$ are two elements and $[a,b]\neq 1$ then $[a,b]$ is not a proper power $c^n$ of $c$.

By (a), we can suppose that $F$ is generated by $a,b,c$. If $d$ is the rank of $F$, it is also the rank of its abelianization, and the relation $[a,b]=c^n$ then forces $d\le 2$. Also $d\ge 2$ since $a,b$ don't commute. So $F$ is free on 2 generators (up to now this is exactly Baumslag's argument).

Hence $L=F/[F,[F,F]]$ is free 2-step nilpotent on 2 generators. Denote by $A,B,C$ the images of $a,b,c$ in $L$. Since $L/[L,L]$ is torsion-free and $C^n\in [L,L]$, we have $C\in [L,L]$. By (d), we deduce that $L$ is generated by $A,B$. So the endomorphism of $L$ mapping the two free generators to $A$ and $B$ is surjective. By (c) deduce that $L$ is free 2-step nilpotent on $(A,B)$. Since $[A,B]=C^n$, we can use (a) to get a contradiction. (Baumslag's conclusion of the argument also uses a 2-step nilpotent group, but I haven't followed as it's more technical)

Comment: Iirc, this is very similar to Baumslag's argument (though he uses the Hopf-ness of the pro-p completion).

Comment: @HJRW, Andreas said that Baumslag's proof relies "on various technical computations and is hard to grasp". I hope you don't find this about this proof (even if it's the same in spirit).

Comment: I agree that Baumslag's proof may not look like this at first glance. But I think it's essentially the same.

Comment: @HJRW no problem. I claim no originality, it's an exercise anyway.

Comment: It's very nice! I just thought it might be good to connect the dots.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this proof shows that the same statement holds for any group with the property that each non-cyclic subgroup surjects to the free 2-step nilpotent group with 2 generators. Is there a name for this class of groups? (Something like "locally residually Heisenberg", perhaps.)

Comment: @VictorProtsak It seems correct, although this condition discards $\mathbf{Z}^2$ subgroups while you don't need to... the condition for 3-generated non-abelian subgroups is enough, for instance. Also, it's true for residually free groups, which may contain $\mathbf{Z}^2$ (if $[a,b]=c^n$, map to a free group in which $c$ has a nontrivial image). (I don't know if one class of this kind deserves a name, but certainly I'd avoid "locally residually X" as I use "locally residually finite" for groups all of whose f.g. subgroups are residually finite.

Comment: Thanks. But (in light of what you explained) can't you just use (a) and (b). By (b) the group $H$ generated by $a,b,c$ is free and looking at its abelianization one sees that it must be a free group on two generators. Moreover, the images of $a,b$ generate the abelianization. Thus, $H/[H,[H,H]]$ is the Heisenberg group and wlog the images of $a,b$ are the standard generators (plus something in the center). Thus, $[a,b]$ maps to the generator of the center, which is easily seen not to be a power.

Comment: @AndreasThom yes (instead of the easy facts c-d, you then use transitivity of $Aut(F_2)$ on generating pairs of the abelianization $\mathbf{Z}^2$, i.e. surjectivity of $Aut(F_2)\to GL_2(\mathbf{Z})$, which is also easy and standard).

Comment: @YCor, I think I just used that any automorphism of $\mathbb Z^2$ can be lifted to the Heisenberg group.

Answer (score 4):

There is a visualisation of Schützenberger's
observation based on a variant of the
[car-crash lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2387) that says that

> for any multiple motion
> on a map on a closed oriented
> surface $S$, the
> number of points of complete collision is at least
> $\chi(S)+\sum\limits_D(d_D-1)$,
> where the summation runs over all
> faces $D$ of the map
> and $d_D$ is the number of cars moving around a face $D$.

See
[[this self-advertisement]](http://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02861)
for exact definitions.

So, if a non-identity commutator in a free group $F(x,y,\dots)$ is, e.g.,
a cube of a word $c$, we obtain a one-face map on a torus, where the
label of the face is $c^3$. Let three cars move around this face
counter-clockwise
with a
constant speed one edge per a minute; at a moment
$t$ each car moves along an edge labelled by the $[t]$th letter
of the word $c$ (where the integer part $[t]$
of $t\in\mathbb R$ is counted modulo the length of $c$).

[image: 3 cars on a torus]

The car-crash lemma asserts that
$$
\small
\pmatrix{
\hbox{the number of points}
\\\\ 
\hbox{of complete collision}
}
\geqslant
\begin{pmatrix}
\hbox{the Euler characteristic}
\\\\ 
\hbox{of the torus,}
\\\\
\hbox{i.e. 0}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\pmatrix{
\hbox{$d_D$, i.e. the number of cars}
\\\\
\hbox{moving around the unique face $D$,}
\\\\
\hbox{i.e. 3}
}
-1=2.
%}
$$
On the other hand, a collision inside an edge is impossible:

[image: Cars colliding inside an edge]

such a collision would imply that some letter of the word
$c$ is $x$ and $x^{-1}$ simultaneously. A similar argument shows
that a collision at a vertex cannot occur too. This contradiction
proves that a commutator cannot be a cube.

This approach was used in
[[this self-advertisement]](http://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02861),
[[this self-advertisement]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01379),
and
[[this self-advertisement]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7908)
to obtain generalisations of
Schützenberger's observation
and
Duncan--Howie's
theorem ([mentioned by Henry Wilton](https://mathoverflow.net/a/256737)).